# Why is my M1 MacBook Pro ignoring a specific USB-C Drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, ventura

I have a 13-inch, M1, 2020 MacBook Pro that is ignoring a specific Lacie USB-C SSD drive. It doesn't matter which USB-C port I plug it into.

It's not the M1's USB ports. I can plug other devices (including another Lacie SSD) in and they work just fine.

It's not the Lacie drive. It works when I plug it into two different MacBook Pros and an iMac Pro.

All Macs are running macOS 13.5.

### Overview

I have used this drive with my M1 daily for over a year. Yesterday, I reimaged my M1 and reinstalled macOS. Today I plugged in the drive and it performed this loop:

1. Show screen asking if I want to allow the accessory to connect
2. Before I can click Allow, the dialog disappears
3. After about a second, go back to step #1.

I put my mouse where the "Allow" button was and kept clicking until finally I managed to click it before it disappeared.

Now my M1 doesn't recognize the drive at all. No prompt to allow it. The drive does light up but never shows up in Disk Utility or System Information.

#### What I've tried

- Rebooting the machine
- A different USB-C cable
- Putting a USB-C hub between the drive and the M1. This actually worked for about a second before the drive disappeared again and I got a "Disk Not Ejected Properly" notification.

Comment: Does it show up in Disk Utility?  Run `diskutil list` to see if it's there. Also see if it shows up under the USB devices. Run `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` and see if you can find your drive.  You might try appending `| grep -i lacie` to filter for it.  I'm assuming that name is in the USB identifier - it may not be so fall back to the command without the pipe.